# How do I call a jQuery live event from inside itself?

Tags: jquery

I wanting to know if anyone knows away of calling a live event inside itself with a parameter.

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', {param: param1), function(event) {
     alert(event.data.param);
     $('#mybutton').click('some data');
});
```

I had found something weird in my code which was causing the trigger event not to work.

Here is a clean version that should work.

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', {param: param1), function(event) {
     alert(event.data.param);
     $('#mybutton').trigger('click', ['some data']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) lets you specify additional parameters. They'll show up as extra arguments to the function rather than as items on the `event.data` object, but they'll get there...

Here's an example ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/igihuj/2)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theButton").live('click', {foo: "bar"}, function(event, second) {
    display("event.data.foo = " + event.data.foo);
    display("second arg = " + second);
  });

  $("#theTrigger").click(function() {
    $("#theButton").trigger('click', "charlie");
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

But wanting to trigger event handlers in this way usually indicates that things want a bit of refactoring. Have a function that does the work you want done, and then *call* that function when you want the work done — either in response to an event, or directly when you need to do the work directly (rather than triggering the event, which is indirect and not terribly clear from a maintenance perspective).

E.g.:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', {param: param1), function(event) {
    doSomething(event.data.param);
});

function doSomething(param) {
    // ...do something with `param`...

    // Possibly call yourself again
    if (some_condition) {
        doSomething(some_other_param_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works on bind events and I can't use bind events. I have to use live events, however, the jQuery site does say that live can have eventData which is the same as bind. Its trying to work out the right way of triggering the event.

Comment: @Sam: No, `trigger` works with handlers hooked up via `live` as well. I've updated the example to use `live` rather than `bind`. But either way, refactoring is more likely the way to go.

Comment: From what I have been reading the trigger is unable to trigger live events from inside itself.

Comment: @Sam: Have you ***tried*** it? What you're reading is wrong: http://jsbin.com/igihuj/3

Comment: What I am need to do is trigger the button click event but with a parameter so that it will do something different. I can easily put what I want it to do where I am trying to trigger it, but I thought re clicking the button and getting to do the job that it already can do with out me repeating myself would be useful.

Comment: @Sam: That's a convoluted way to solve the problem. The better answer is refactoring. There's no repeating yourself involved. You have one function that does the work, and two places calling that one function: One external (the event handler), the other internal (the function itself).

Comment: The way that I have my code set up is that when I click one of my buttons it runs the same event. Then depending one what button is run it will do something. Then what I am trying to do is when one of the buttons has finished what it is doing it will trigger another button which is in the same live event. However, I have tried many different ways of triggering the live event within it self without doing multiple click events.

Comment: I have found that part of my code was causing the trigger event not to work. I don't understand but it was like it was conflicting with it, I have altered it and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but I think your `live` code is a little off:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(event, param) {
  alert(param);
  $('#mybutton').trigger('click', ['some data']);
});
```

Also,

```
$('#mybutton').trigger('click', 'some data');
```

is only compatible with jQuery 1.6.2. Wrapping it in an array

```
$('#mybutton').trigger('click', ['some data']);
```

is much more backwards compatible.

Comment: You're right, you have to use `trigger` instead of `click`. Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/uyivor